# What is the difference between a function and a class constructor?

Tags: c++, c++17

Can't figure out what is the difference between `h1` and `h2` in the code below:

```
#include <utility>

template <class Func>
struct Holder
{
    Holder(Func && func) : m_func(std::forward<Func>(func))
    {
    }

    Func m_func;
};

template <class Func>
auto MakeHolder(Func && func)
{
    return Holder<Func>(std::forward<Func>(func));
}

int main()
{
    auto func = [](int val) {};

    Holder h1 = MakeHolder(func);

    Holder<decltype(func)> h2(func);

    return 0;
}
```

Why `h1` compiles, but `h2` does not? The error with GCC is

```
prog.cc:25 : 31 : error : cannot bind rvalue reference of type 'main()::<lambda(int)>&&' to lvalue of type 'main()::<lambda(int)>'
    25 | Holder<decltype(func)> h2(func);
```

Are types `Func` in the function template arguments and `decltype<func>` in `main()` different?

Comment: The error message says it. In your ctor you accept an argument of type `Func &&` yet `func` is an lvalue of type `Func`.

Comment: Why are your ctor taking a forwarding reference anyway?

Comment: I think the reason for the difference is because a function does template type deduction, whereas in the class version, you're explicitly stating it (incorrectly in this case).

Comment: @einpoklum Did you mean why do I use `std::forward<Func>` in ctor?

Comment: @AmiTavory are `Func` and `decltype<func>` different types?

Comment: @Dmitriano an l-value to func, is not the same as an rvalue to it, for example, similar to how const reference to func is not exactly a func. I'd guess that the reason for the difference is a combination of template function type resolution + some rules (which I don't remember) about what rvalues to other types of values become. I'm less into C++ these days.

Comment: @Dmitriano: 1. Yes, no need for the forwarding reference and std::forward in the ctor - you're not forwarding to some other templated function.

Comment: The compilation error is due to `&&` being overloaded, depending on context, as either an rvalue reference or a universal reference. It is an rvalue reference in the constructor, and ***not*** a forwarding reference.

Comment: I think this question is more specific than the dupe target. It's asking about specifically how decltype works here. Voting to reopen.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik So the function parameter is of type `& &&` and the constructor parameter is of type `&&` right?

Comment: I don't know what "type `& &&`" means. There is no such "type" in C++.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik what do you know then?

Comment: What I know are the things that are described in the duplicate question.

Answer (score 0):

The difference is that the Holder class is instantiated with different types for `Func`:

1. For `h1`, it's `main()::<lambda(int)>&`
2. For `h2`, it's `main()::<lambda(int)>`

You see, when you have a variable of type T and use it, the type of the use is not the same as that of the variable: `T&` instead of `T`. But in `decltype()` the semantics are different.

Anyway, you can get your code to compile like so:

```
#include <utility>

template <class Func>
struct Holder
{
    Holder(Func func) : m_func(func) { }

    Func m_func;
};

template <class Func>
auto MakeHolder(Func && func)
{
    return Holder<Func>(std::forward<Func>(func));
}

int main()
{
    auto func = [](int) {};
    [[maybe_unused]] Holder h1 = MakeHolder(func);
    [[maybe_unused]] Holder<decltype(func)> h2(func);
}
```

[<kbd>GodBolt</kbd>](https://godbolt.org/z/r7adaW)

Or if you really must - use `std::move(func)` in the initializer list. But - I'm not sure I would keep a `Func` member, for arbitrary `Func` (e.g. when it's a reference or a pointer to something temporary that may go away.

Comment: So the function parameter is of type `main()::<lambda(int)>& &&` that collapses to `main()::<lambda(int)>&`, right?

Comment: If so, my function creates `Holder<main()::<lambda(int)>&>` that keeps the reference, but the the value.

Comment: I have an impression that I need `std::decay` here.